# Query to get specific data in database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I want to retrieve data from the database that will conform to the following specs.

The current variables are: Date and Shift

I want to retrieve data that are equal to today's date and the shift is equal to "C"

I do get results but then here comes the problem:

I also get the results from the previous day's "C" shift

Reason why is because the shifts are as follows...

```
Shift A = 05:45 - 13:45

Shift B = 13:45 - 21:45

Shift C = 21:45 - 05:45
```

That means that I get the previous day's data because the date is the same for the previous shift C because it overlap 2 days

How can I write a query to only retrieve the data for a specific C shift?

My current query is:

`SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Shift = currentshift AND Date = todayDate`

Comment: Is your shift time data in two separate columns, i.e. `Start Time` - `End Time`?  If so, you could add `WHERE End-Time > 6:00`

Comment: How does your database/query handle shifts that cross multiple dates? Eg: Shift C? Do shifts have StartTime and EndTime?

Comment: Could you please let us know how the data is stored? With above information, there can be so many answers/ combinations...

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed yes start and end time is in two separate columns but the night shift does not always stay the same, e.g. Shift A and B can also be night shift.

Comment: @CallumBradbury no the shifts doesn't have start and end time, only the pallets produced within those shifts

Comment: Can you provide sample data in a *tabular* format and expected results?

Comment: You didn't specify the criteria according to which one shift is counted as `current date` or `current date -1` , so I assumed if the shift ends before 6 am, safe to say it was previous day's night shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is this:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Data d
WHERE CAST(@DATE as TIME) >= '21:45:00') OR
      CAST(@DATE as TIME) <= '05:45:00')
```

You also need a condition on the date.  I'm not sure what that looks like with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Am assuming you want to filter shift with time and not by date so your SQL query would be something like this

```
IsNull(LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(0),Shift ),5),'00:00') > @startTime and 
IsNull(LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(0),Shift ),5),'00:00') < @endTime
```

---

**Updated:**

Another way is to create dynamic query and based on condition append the where clause

```
DECLARE @currentshift nvarchar(150);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @todayDate datetime;
--set @todayDate=getdate();
--set @Date=GETDATE();
--set @currentshift='shift c'

Set @SQL=N'SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Shift='''+@currentshift+'''';
IF  (@currentshift ='21:45 - 05:45')
    begin
        set @SQL =@SQL+ ' and [Date] >='''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@todayDate, 101)+''' and [Date] <='''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,1,''+@todayDate+''), 101)+'''';
    end
ELSE 
    begin
        set @SQL =@SQL+ ' and [Date] ='''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@todayDate, 101)+'''';
    end
-- print @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but this filters whether a shift both started and ended on the same day, right? In that case, it does not answer OP's question regarding shifts ending on next day